# Busy line when accessing microphone in Java (Updated)

Tags: java, windows, microphone

I have a java desktop application over Windows that requests access to a microphone line and a speaker line, it usually works correctly but in a particular case it does not get access to the microphone.

I have moved that part of the code to a separate application to look for the problem.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lineasaudio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Line;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;

public class LineasAudio {

static final int INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE = 40960;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creating a File object that represents the disk file. 
    PrintStream o = null;
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
        o = new PrintStream(new File("TEST" + dtf.format(now) + ".txt"));
        // Assign o to output stream 
        System.setOut(o);
        System.setErr(o);
        System.out.println(dtf.format(now));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LineasAudio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // TODO code application logic here
    initMicrophoneLine();
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    initSpeakerLine();
}

public static void initMicrophoneLine() {
    System.out.println("Input Available Mixers:");
    Mixer.Info[] aInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < aInfos.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("   " + i + ") " + aInfos[i].getName() + ": " + aInfos[i].getDescription() + "\n");
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(aInfos[i]);
        Line.Info[] targetLineInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info info : targetLineInfo) {
            showLineInfo(info);
        }
    }
    if (aInfos.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("WARNING: NO mixers available.");
        return;
    }

    float fFrameRate = 8000.0F;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, fFrameRate, 16, 1, 2, fFrameRate, false);
    Boolean microphone = false;
    TargetDataLine target_line = null;
    boolean DEBUG = true;

    DataLine.Info lineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format, INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(lineInfo)) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: AudioLine not supported by this System.");
    }
    try {
        target_line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("TargetDataLine: " + target_line);
        }
        target_line.open(format, INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
        microphone = true;
        System.out.println("Microphone line found");
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: LineUnavailableException at AudioSender()");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: microphone not found");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (!microphone) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: microphone not found");
        }
    }

}

public static void initSpeakerLine() {
    System.out.println("Output Available Mixers:");
    Mixer.Info[] aInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < aInfos.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("   " + i + ") " + aInfos[i].getName() + ": " + aInfos[i].getDescription() + "\n");
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(aInfos[i]);
        Line.Info[] sourceLineInfo = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info info : sourceLineInfo) {
            showLineInfo(info);
        }
    }
    if (aInfos.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("WARNING: NO mixers available.");
        return;
    }

    float fFrameRate = 8000.0F;
    AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, fFrameRate, 16, 1, 2, fFrameRate, false);
    Boolean speaker = false;

    SourceDataLine source_line;
    boolean DEBUG = true;

    DataLine.Info lineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format, INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(lineInfo)) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: AudioLine not supported by this System.");
    }
    try {
        source_line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("SourceDataLine: " + source_line);
        }
        source_line.open(format, INTERNAL_BUFFER_SIZE);
        speaker = true;
        System.out.println("Speaker line found");
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: LineUnavailableException at AudioReceiver()");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: speaker or headphones not found");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (!speaker) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: speaker not found");
        }
    }
}

public static void displayMixerInfo() {
    Mixer.Info[] mixersInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    for (Mixer.Info mixerInfo : mixersInfo) {
        System.out.println("Mixer: " + mixerInfo.getName());

        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);

        Line.Info[] sourceLineInfo = mixer.getSourceLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info info : sourceLineInfo) {
            showLineInfo(info);
        }

        Line.Info[] targetLineInfo = mixer.getTargetLineInfo();
        for (Line.Info info : targetLineInfo) {
            showLineInfo(info);
        }

    }
}

private static void showLineInfo(final Line.Info lineInfo) {
    System.out.println("  " + lineInfo.toString());

    if (lineInfo instanceof DataLine.Info) {
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = (DataLine.Info) lineInfo;

        AudioFormat[] formats = dataLineInfo.getFormats();
        for (final AudioFormat format : formats) {
            System.out.println("    " + format.toString());
        }
    }
}

}
```

The result obtained has been:

```
2020-01-22_16-37-03
Input Available Mixers:
   0) Controlador primario de sonido: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   1) Teléfono con altavoz con cancelación de eco (Jabra SPEAK 510 USB): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   2) Digital Output (S/PDIF) (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   3) Altavoces / Auricular (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   4) AMD HDMI Output (AMD High Definition Audio Device): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   5) Comunicaciones auriculares (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   6) Controlador primario de captura de sonido: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture
  interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   7) Teléfono con altavoz con cancel: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture
  interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   8) Micrófono (USB Audio Device): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture
  interface TargetDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   9) Port Teléfono con altavoz con cancel: Port Mixer
  HEADPHONE target port
   10) Port Digital Output (S/PDIF) (IDT Hi: Port Mixer
  Volumen general target port
   11) Port Altavoces / Auricular (IDT High: Port Mixer
  SPEAKER target port
   12) Port AMD HDMI Output (AMD High Defin: Port Mixer
  Volumen general target port
   13) Port Comunicaciones auriculares (IDT: Port Mixer
  HEADPHONE target port
   14) Port Micrófono (USB Audio Device): Port Mixer
  Volumen general target port
   15) Port Teléfono con altavoz con cancel: Port Mixer
  Volumen general target port
TargetDataLine: com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectTDL@c34f4d
ERROR: LineUnavailableException at AudioSender()
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_SIGNED 8000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(Unknown Source)
    at lineasaudio.LineasAudio.initMicrophoneLine(LineasAudio.java:91)
    at lineasaudio.LineasAudio.main(LineasAudio.java:53)
ERROR: microphone not found


Output Available Mixers:
   0) Controlador primario de sonido: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   1) Teléfono con altavoz con cancelación de eco (Jabra SPEAK 510 USB): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   2) Digital Output (S/PDIF) (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   3) Altavoces / Auricular (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   4) AMD HDMI Output (AMD High Definition Audio Device): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
   interface SourceDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   interface Clip supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   5) Comunicaciones auriculares (IDT High Definition Audio CODEC): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Playback
  interface SourceDataLine supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
  interface Clip supporting 8 audio formats, and buffers of at least 32 bytes
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, big-endian
    PCM_UNSIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 8 bit, stereo, 2 bytes/frame, 
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
    PCM_SIGNED unknown sample rate, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, big-endian
   6) Controlador primario de captura de sonido: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture
   7) Teléfono con altavoz con cancel: Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture
   8) Micrófono (USB Audio Device): Direct Audio Device: DirectSound Capture
   9) Port Teléfono con altavoz con cancel: Port Mixer
   10) Port Digital Output (S/PDIF) (IDT Hi: Port Mixer
   11) Port Altavoces / Auricular (IDT High: Port Mixer
   12) Port AMD HDMI Output (AMD High Defin: Port Mixer
   13) Port Comunicaciones auriculares (IDT: Port Mixer
   14) Port Micrófono (USB Audio Device): Port Mixer
  MICROPHONE source port
   15) Port Teléfono con altavoz con cancel: Port Mixer
  MICROPHONE source port
SourceDataLine: com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectSDL@817b38
Speaker line found
```

In addition I have tried with [the oracle sample application](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasounddemo-140014.html), which I have verified that the problem is not the specified audio options, but that the line appears as busy when requested from the system. It happens on an HP brand desktop computer with a Jabra conference microphone on Windows, so in principle I thought it would be a problem with the microphone controller since it is a USB microphone, but when testing with a jack microphone it also happens.

My opinion is that it could be the fault of the IDT audio drivers but I can't uninstall them because they are the primary system. Windows perfectly recognizes the microphone and I have also tried to close the rest of applications that could be blocking the line, like Skype, but problem persists.

Is there any way I can release that line or walkaround the problem? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

The tests performed modifying all possible parameters to get the audio line have given the same result. Nor has it worked to try to get the line from the mixer directly. Every time I get access to the line but trying to open it generates the exception as if it were busy. I have also tried to close the line before trying to open it to try to free the line but I have obtained the same result

Comment: Java audio is hard to work with. In my experience, you cannot rely on it to work flawlessly with all audio cards. You need to test it and adapt configuration for different cards. I don't have experience with java audio on windows, I have used it on linux pc's and raspberry pi's with different audio cards.

Comment: @Christine Thanks, but I don't know how to adapt the settings for different cards because "AudioSystem.isLineSupported" tells me that the format is compatible and I can get the line, an error occurs when I try to open the line.

Comment: @Christine I write an update with new test results